# Data structure to implement aging of a mac address table entry in C

Tags: c, data-structures, timer

I would like to understand the concept of timing wheels which are supposed to be used for aging MAC address table entries. Pointer to any code in C also would be helpful. I searched the net but couldn't find a convincing answer. Just for reference, a MAC address table entry would like the following:

```
Vlan     MAC Address         Type    Age(s)     Port
-----------------------------------------------------
100      0000.0001.0009     dynamic   50         Po1

100      0000.0001.0010     dynamic   60         Po1

200      001d.7172.6c40     dynamic   300        Eth100/1/20
```

For each entry i should be able to decrement the age value and remove an entry if age = 0.

There is mention of a timing wheel data structure on the net, but i don't know how it can be used in the above case.

Thank you,
Vij

Comment: Why would you decrement an *age*?  Things only get older over time.

Comment: Sorry, do you have any code we can discuss onto?

Comment: @MattTimmermans, I think he is just talking about Time To Live, instead, so when it reaches 0 or negative, can drop the entry..... but without the code he is using it is impossible to see what he pretends.

Comment: It's a timeout (not TTL) after which the entry is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually store the age (or time-to-live), so you don't have to modify those values over time.  Instead you store the creation time and/or expiry time, and subtract with the current time when you need to show an age or TTL.

A "timing wheel" in this context is a kind if circular buffer where each slot contains a list of all the items that expire at the same time.  There's a pretty good introductory discussion here: https://blog.acolyer.org/2015/11/23/hashed-and-hierarchical-timing-wheels/

Comment: I saw the link which was posted, but I would like to know more on the implementation aspects.